# How do you compile a static library that has a 3rd party dependency without including the dependency?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

TL;DR

- How do I build a static library without including a third party library that I'm referencing?

---

Hi,

Before I begin, I know how to compile a static library in Xcode targeted for iOS devices and simulators. However, this time around I have a dependency on a third party library **that I do not want to include** in the static library. I simply want to reference it. However, whenever I am building my static library I get a **lexical or preprocessor error**, which I know is common when the library is missing from the project. The error occurs because I removed the library from the project, because I didn't want to have it built into the static library.

The library in question is AFNetworking. I will be using CocoaPods to explicitly have the dependency installed when installing my static library.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like every static library would access other libraries that aren't compiled into the project.  Try just having the header files for the other library in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What would happen when someone downloads the entire library as it's a required dependency? Would a duplicate symbol error occur as their are now two copies of the .h files.

Comment: It shouldn't. You can include the same .h file in multiple .m's. I used to have sub-projects inside of my main project. At compile time it would compile the libraries and then compile the main app.  And these libraries actually referenced each other and the way you made them aware about the other libraries was to include all of their .h files.  But are you sure that if you compile a .a that it will include other .a's anyway?  I wouldn't think so.

Comment: Well, AFNetworking isn't a static library. It's totally open source, so I have it imported in my project. In the closed-source version of my project, I only want to reference AFNetworking, but not actually include it in the final .a That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do, if it's even possible. The best example I can think of is to consider AFNetworkign like <Foundation> or <UIKit> or <AVFoundation>. I can compile my .a without including those libraries. I want to do the same with this third party library.

Comment: Sorry.. that's all I got.  it's above my pay grade.  :)

Comment: No problem - your comment was on the mark, as a few people have now mentioned it. @alloy gave the same answer, but elaborated on it. I guess I just had a knowledge-gap in my head, which is why your answer didn't make 100% sense to me. Thank you! Upvoted both your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference external code, you will *always* need to have the headers accessible by your project, otherwise the compiler wouldn’t be able to tell you if you are referencing the external code in a proper manner. E.g. does the method exist, are you providing the right types, etc.

The duplicate symbol problem *only* exists when you actually define a symbol multiple times. For instance, defining class related Objective-C symbols *only* happens in a `@implementation...@end` block, **not** in a `@interface...@end` block. The latter is only for the compiler to make sense of things.

(This is also why you can define a `@interface` for e.g. a private class and use it as normal and not cause duplicate symbols.)

Therefore, you can include such ‘clean’ headers multiple times without having to worry about it. Note that I said ‘clean’, because you *can* actually define symbols in headers by, for instance, defining C functions in headers or even a Objective-C `@implementation`, if you feel especially wicked. But you will simply have to test this.

The linker will complain when you finally link the 3rd-party dependency and yours and there were duplicate symbols after all. In that case, be sure to look into tools such as `nm` which list the symbols in an archive.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for demystifying the reasons for the duplicate symbols issue! Marked your answer as correct. Quick follow up question. What if the third party developer who has my SDK updates AFNetworking, and the methods change or disappear? Which .h file takes precedence? The one loaded inside my static lib, or the ones declared in new .h file. Or does it not matter, as long as they have a .m file with the actual definitions that match the .h file?

Comment: It’s probably best to forget about the headers. ‘Clean’ headers are only for the compiler, they’re not included in the build.

Comment: Ok, cool. So I'll just include the AFNetworking and UIKit+AFNetworking headers in my static lib before compilation. If anything breaks down the road, I'll fix it. Expect a Specs/ pull request from me later today! :)

Comment: In your case you really mean API compatibility. There’s no much that can be done about this, in order of my personal pref: 1) State required version in your documentation. 2) If dependency (e.g. AFNetworking) exposes a ‘version’, check that. 3) Check for expected methods at runtime and assert those (although this doesn’t guard against methods existing, but having changed).

Comment: All in all, this transitive dependencies issue is exactly what CocoaPods tries to solve ;)

Comment: Off-topic: I clearly don’t understand how SO works. I submitted my first comment too early because I expected to insert a newline.

Comment: Ah gotcha, you want to publish it through CocoaPods. Then please look into http://semver.org. We can’t ensure all libs follow it, but I do believe AFNetworking does, which means you can depend on it with a version requirement like so `~> 2`, which _should_ guard against API changes.

Comment: Greta, was going to do that anyway, just in case. Thanks for confirming that's the way to go about doing it!

Answer (score 1):

you can add the lib.a and lib.h into your project.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding the the third party library into my project as it gets compiled into the main library. Is there a way to pick/choose which files get placed inside a static library from within the Xcode project?

Comment: why are you need this ?

Comment: if you want to pick/choose which files to compiled into the main library ,you can add those files that what you need in to your main project .

Comment: Got it - thank you! Your answer was part right, so I will vote it up!